# Sorting Listview control columns with integer values in Powershell forms

Tags: forms, powershell, listview, type-conversion, columnsorting

I am trying to sort the column "Size (kb)" in the following Listview. The "Size (kb)" column is getting sorted on basis of the text value which is not the intended result. I am getting correct results for all other columns

```
# Defining the listbox fo displaying the search results
$lvw_resultsListView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView -Property @{
    View        = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Details
    Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10, 40)  
    Width       = 700
    Height      = 350
    Scrollable  = $true
    MultiSelect = $true
    Font        = 'Arial,10'
    AutoSize    = $true
    Sorting     = "Ascending"
    FullRowSelect = $true
    GridLines = $True
}
```

Here is the code that adds columns to the Listview

```
# Adding Columns to List View
$lvw_resultsListView.columns.Add("Filename", 150) | Out-Null
$lvw_resultsListView.columns.Add("Path", 340) | Out-Null
$lvw_resultsListView.columns.Add("Size (kb)", 90) | Out-Null
$lvw_resultsListView.columns.Add("Created on", 70) | Out-Null
$lvw_resultsListView.columns.Add("Ext", 60) | Out-Null
```

Here is the code that adds values from  a file object

```
# Clearing list view items
$lvw_resultsListView.Items.Clear()
# Adding file information to the list bx by cycling through each file
foreach ($file in $global:files) {
    $fileItem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem( $file.BaseName)
    $fileItem.Subitems.Add($file.FullName) | Out-Null
    $fileItem.Subitems.Add($file.Length) | Out-Null
    $tempCreationDate = $file.CreationTime | Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $fileItem.Subitems.Add($tempCreationDate) | Out-Null
    $fileItem.Subitems.Add($file.Extension) | Out-Null
    $lvw_resultsListView.Items.Add($fileItem) | Out-Null
}
```

And here is the sorting function that is called on column click

```
function SortListView {
    Param(
        [System.Windows.Forms.ListView] $senderPsItem,
        $column
    )
    $temp = $senderPsItem.Items | Foreach-Object { $_ }
    $Script:SortingDescending = !$Script:SortingDescending
    $senderPsItem.Items.Clear()
    $senderPsItem.ShowGroups = $false
    $senderPsItem.Sorting = 'none'
    
    if($column.Text -eq "Size (kb)") {
        
        $senderPsItem.Items.AddRange(($temp | Sort-Object -Descending:$script:SortingDescending -Property @{ Expression={ [int]$_.SubItems[$column].Text } }))
        
    } else {
        $senderPsItem.Items.AddRange(($temp | Sort-Object -Descending:$script:SortingDescending -Property @{ Expression={ $_.SubItems[$column].Text } }))

    }
}
```

Here(snippet from the results form) is a sample result I am getting for the "Size (kb)" column

[image]

Here is the code calling sorting function

```
$lvw_resultsListView.Add_ColumnClick({SortListView $this $_.Column})
```

Could someone suggest a way to improve my sort function to properly sort the integer column. I tried converting the test to integer by using [int] method as may be seen from the sorting function?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Put a `Write-Host $temp` below the variable assignment and click the column you want to sort, it will help understand why your function is not working. An advice, you might wanna look at `DataGridView` with `DataTable` as data source. It will be a lot easier to code.

Comment: Wow! That really helped. Thanks Santiago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IF condition for checking the column "Size (kb)" was not correct. The column index was used to fix this.

Changed

> if($column.Text -eq "Size (kb)")

to

> if($column -eq 2)

I updated the sorting unction to correct the IF condition

```
function SortListView {
    Param(
        [System.Windows.Forms.ListView] $senderPsItem,
        $column
    )
    $temp = $senderPsItem.Items | Foreach-Object { $_ }
    $Script:SortingDescending = !$Script:SortingDescending
    $senderPsItem.Items.Clear()
    $senderPsItem.ShowGroups = $false
    $senderPsItem.Sorting = 'none'
    Write-Host $column
    
    if($column -eq 2) {
        
        $senderPsItem.Items.AddRange(($temp | Sort-Object -Descending:$script:SortingDescending -Property @{ Expression={ [int]$_.SubItems[$column].Text } }))
        
    } else {
        $senderPsItem.Items.AddRange(($temp | Sort-Object -Descending:$script:SortingDescending -Property @{ Expression={ $_.SubItems[$column].Text } }))

    }
}
```

This gives the correct results for the integer column.

Answer (score 1):

Here, try out this code, it will help you understand why I mentioned `DataGridView` and `DataTable`, this personally made a big impact for me when working with Windows Forms.

Try sorting the `*Time` and `Length` columns and you'll understand why :)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

$myFont='Helvetica'

$mainForm=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$mainForm.StartPosition='CenterScreen'
$mainForm.Icon=[System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$PSHOME\PowerShell.exe")
$mainForm.KeyPreview=$True
$mainForm.FormBorderStyle='Fixed3D'
$mainForm.Text='Test'
$mainForm.WindowState='Maximized'

$bounds=($mainForm.CreateGraphics()).VisibleClipBounds.Size

$dataGrid=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGrid.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($bounds.Width-20),$($bounds.Height-140))
$dataGrid.Location=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,60)
$dataGrid.Font=New-Object System.Drawing.Font($myFont,9,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$dataGrid.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode='True'
$dataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows=$false
$dataGrid.SelectionMode=0
$dataGrid.MultiSelect=$True
$dataGrid.ReadOnly=$false
$dataGrid.EnableHeadersVisualStyles=$True
$datagrid.Anchor='Top, Bottom, Left'
$mainForm.Controls.Add($dataGrid)

#Here goes your Data Source
$dataSource = Get-ChildItem "$HOME\Documents" -File|select Name,Length,LastWriteTime,CreationTime

$columns=$dataSource[0].PSobject.Properties.Name
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable

foreach($column in $columns)
{
    $type=switch -Wildcard($column)
    {
        'Length'{[int]}
        '*Time'{[datetime]}
        Default{[string]}
    }

    $i = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn
    $i.DataType = $type
    $i.ColumnName = $column
    $table.Columns.Add($i)
}

foreach($line in $dataSource)
{
    $row = $table.NewRow()
    
    foreach($column in $columns)
    {
        $row.$column = $line.$column
    }

    $table.Rows.Add($row)
}

# Here you bind your DataSource to your DataGridView
$dataGrid.DataSource=$table

$dataGrid.RowHeadersVisible=$false
$dataGrid.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle=2
$dataGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode=[System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode]::AllCells
$dataGrid.ColumnHeadersHeight=25

$sum=0
$dataGrid.Columns.Width|%{$sum+=$_}

if($sum -lt $dataGrid.Width)
{
    $dataGrid.Columns[-1].AutoSizeMode=[System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode]::Fill
}


$mainForm.ShowDialog()
```